# DrawUserPrimitives will only use a few colors

Tags: c#, xna, drawing

**EDIT**

This was from a bug in my *my own code* that was causing the error, not XNA. It seemed that my color-loading function was bugged but I didn't realize.

**ORIGINAL**

I'm experimenting with drawing in 3D using VertexPositionColor, and I've gotten pretty much everything down, except that when I try to draw using a specific color, it always converts it to one of about 7 colors, like the ones seen here:

[image: colors] (plus Yellow and White)

I've been trying to draw part of something using Color.Gray (128, 128, 128, 255), but it just doesn't seem to work, it just converts it to white.

This is what it looks like, and what it ought to look like:

[image: current]
[image: desired]

Is there any reason why this happens, or any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your shader just not uses color.
You use your own shader or standard?
Try use BasicEffect and call his method EnableDefaultLighting() when drawing.

[There](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials) is a great series of articles on programming the on XNA.
[There's](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/basic-effect-lighting) all described in detail. I think you can find the answer to your question.

If you need more detailed answer please add some code to your question.